# WxPython GUI is flipped to LTR

Tags: windows, wxpython

Working for quite a while with a WxPython GUI. A very weird issue occurred when it opened as LTR on a windows PC. Some frames were really messed up because of that.

How can I prevent WxPython GUI from flipping?

It should be RTL only.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by going to "Set Regional Format" -> Region -> and changing to "English(United States)"